# Angular guards, unclear statement in the docs

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, guard

I'm trying to understand angular deeply, so i read [the docs](http://angular.io) and it was very helpful.
now i'm studying the guards. and i read this statement in the docs.

> The router checks the CanDeactivate and CanActivateChild guards first, from the deepest child route to the top. Then it checks the CanActivate guards from the top down to the deepest child route.

now i'm confused, why does angular perform it in this way?
is there any benefits of doing the checking from the deepest child to the top for **CanDeactivate** & **CanActivateChild**.  and from top to the deepest child route for **CanActivate**?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had tried to believe what have written in the docs site. However, it appears it's not totally right, or the implementation has been updated but docs doesn't update.

**To be Brief:**

First, `CanDeactivate` guards are checked from *deepest to top* and `CanActivate` guards are checked from *top to deepest*(it will **quit** with falsy check in the traversal).

Second, `CanActivateChild` guards are not checked from *deepest to top*.

---

TL;DR

### Detail Explanation

we should check the source to see how it work.

> Note: the commit checked is: https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/edb8375a5ff15d77709ccf1759efb14091fa86a4

#### step 1 - see when `CanActivateChild` got called

[source here L929](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/edb8375a5ff15d77709ccf1759efb14091fa86a4/packages/router/src/router.ts#L929).

This is only place its superior caller `runCanActivateChild` got called.

At that line, we can get some hint that it does the same trick as `CanActivate`, because `CanActivate`'s superior caller `runCanActivate` is called after.

#### step 2 - see how does `runCanActivateChild` work

[L926](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/edb8375a5ff15d77709ccf1759efb14091fa86a4/packages/router/src/router.ts#L926) and [L950](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/edb8375a5ff15d77709ccf1759efb14091fa86a4/packages/router/src/router.ts#L950).

`runCanActivateChild` got called within the iteration of `canActivateChecks`, same as how `runCanActivate` got called. Here we know `CanActivate`(i mean the feature) and `CanActivateChild` share the same data source -- `canActivateChecks`.

#### step 3 - what is `canActivateChecks` and how does it get processed

So, what is `canActivateChecks`? Obviously, We can find out it's an array of `CanActivate` class instances. But how is `canActivateChecks` got assigned? [Go to here L865](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/edb8375a5ff15d77709ccf1759efb14091fa86a4/packages/router/src/router.ts#L865). This is the important part, so i am going to paste them here.

```typescript
  private traverseChildRoutes(
      futureNode: TreeNode<ActivatedRouteSnapshot>, currNode: TreeNode<ActivatedRouteSnapshot>|null,
      contexts: ChildrenOutletContexts|null, futurePath: ActivatedRouteSnapshot[]): void {
    const prevChildren = nodeChildrenAsMap(currNode);

    // Process the children of the future route
    futureNode.children.forEach(c => {
      this.traverseRoutes(c, prevChildren[c.value.outlet], contexts, futurePath.concat([c.value]));
      delete prevChildren[c.value.outlet];
    });

    // Process any children left from the current route (not active for the future route)
    forEach(
        prevChildren, (v: TreeNode<ActivatedRouteSnapshot>, k: string) =>
                          this.deactivateRouteAndItsChildren(v, contexts !.getContext(k)));
  }

  private traverseRoutes(
      futureNode: TreeNode<ActivatedRouteSnapshot>, currNode: TreeNode<ActivatedRouteSnapshot>,
      parentContexts: ChildrenOutletContexts|null, futurePath: ActivatedRouteSnapshot[]): void {
    const future = futureNode.value;
    const curr = currNode ? currNode.value : null;
    const context = parentContexts ? parentContexts.getContext(futureNode.value.outlet) : null;

    // reusing the node
    if (curr && future._routeConfig === curr._routeConfig) {
      if (this.shouldRunGuardsAndResolvers(
              curr, future, future._routeConfig !.runGuardsAndResolvers)) {
        this.canActivateChecks.push(new CanActivate(futurePath));
        const outlet = context !.outlet !;
        this.canDeactivateChecks.push(new CanDeactivate(outlet.component, curr));
      } else {
        // we need to set the data
        future.data = curr.data;
        future._resolvedData = curr._resolvedData;
      }

      // If we have a component, we need to go through an outlet.
      if (future.component) {
        this.traverseChildRoutes(
            futureNode, currNode, context ? context.children : null, futurePath);

        // if we have a componentless route, we recurse but keep the same outlet map.
      } else {
        this.traverseChildRoutes(futureNode, currNode, parentContexts, futurePath);
      }
    } else {
      // ##### comment by e-cloud #####
      if (curr) {
        this.deactivateRouteAndItsChildren(currNode, context);
      }

      this.canActivateChecks.push(new CanActivate(futurePath));
      // If we have a component, we need to go through an outlet.
      if (future.component) {
        this.traverseChildRoutes(futureNode, null, context ? context.children : null, futurePath);

        // if we have a componentless route, we recurse but keep the same outlet map.
      } else {
        this.traverseChildRoutes(futureNode, null, parentContexts, futurePath);
      }
    }
  }
```

It's a little long. But If you go through it, you would figure out it plays a *depth-first-traversal*. Let's ignore the same route switching. Find `##### comment by e-cloud #####` and see the main procedure. It shows that it updates the `canActivateChecks` first then performs next level travesal(Pre-order traversal at whole).

You must know the router treats all the routes of the app as a url tree. Each `PreActivation` split its `future`(as a tree path) into **path segments** by the traversal.

Take a **simplified** example:

> we have the future route as `/a/b/c`.
>   Then we will get [ '/a', '/a/b', '/a/b/c' ] as `canActivateChecks`

Apparently, `canActivateChecks` represents the routes from top to deepest of the `future`
The source shows `canActivateChecks` is iterated from left to right.

### step 4 - conclusion

**we can conclude that `CanActivateChild` is run from top to deepest child.**

Hope i explain it clearly.

Answer (score 4):

When you think about routing, the deeper into the tree you go, the more specific you get.

For example:

`/food-types/sweets/pies/blueberry`

So when you tell Angular you want to navigate away from the `blueberry` pie, it checks `CanDeactivate` on blueberry first, because you are walking back up the navigation tree, to a different location. `CanActivateChild` will also walk up the tree to the child path, by my understanding, for the same reason: it wants to check the deepest levels first, to verify that their children can be activated.

The converse is true of `CanActivate`. When you tell Angular you want to see the `blueberry` pie, you are walking down the tree, and thus, it checks the guard in order as it walks down the tree.

Comment: good explanation, but what about the CanActivateChild, which explanation it follows?

Comment: Updated - I'm not exactly sure why this is a pattern, but I did my best to explain it.